# cast Obbject to string in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to print map's value bay key in FREEMARKER but got an exception

```
freemarker.core.NonStringException: Error on line 6, column 69 in internal_monitors.ftl 
Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression object[key] is instead a freemarker.template.SimpleSequence
```

this is my code

```
    <#if drives?exists>
<drives><#list drives as object>
    <drive>
    <#list object?keys as key>
        <${key}><#if object[key]?exists>${object[key]}<#else>null</#if></${key}>
    </#list>
    </drive></#list>
</drives>
</#if>
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `??` instead of `?exists`. The `?exists` built-in is deprecated.
2. You have to check, whether the `object[key]` value is displayable (e.g. string, number, date, ...) or a container (hash, sequence). In the later case, you have either to skip it, or iterate its contents:

   ```
   <#if drives??>
       <#list drives as object>
           <drive>
               <#list drive?keys as key>
                   <${key}>
                   <#if object[key]??>
                       <#if object[key]?is_hash>
                           HASH
                       <#elseif object[key]?is_sequence>
                           SEQUENCE
                       <#else>
                           ${object[key]}
                       </#if>
                   <#else>
                       null
                   </#if>
                   </${key}>
               </#list>
           </drive>
       </#list>
   </#if>
   ```

Comment: I am unable to make a proper formatting of my code, here is it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/u2HTHGkV

Comment: `javax.servlet.ServletException: freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected extended hash. drives evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleSequence on line 5, column 18`

Comment: Sorry, my fault, put `object?keys` instead of `drive?keys`!

Comment: sorry meght I resolved the issue thank you very much !